# What are the Salesforce Spring '15 release features?

Tags: administration, release, spring15

As a Salesforce developer, consultant and administrator, I like to stay on top of new features in dev or due to be released in the medium or near future. As the Spring '15 release maintenance exam dates have already been posted I take it that Spring '15 release planning is well under way and so I would like to know ASAP what the new features planned are and when they will be available for pre-release/sandbox trialling.

Comment: As a Salesforce developer, consultant, and administrator, you are likely aware that the release notes for each release are available far in advance of the release date.  They are well written and organized, and available as both a pdf AND html formats.  The ease of availability and format should give you plenty of opportunity to read them for yourself, as the rest of the community also has.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the release notes digest [here](http://www.salesforceweek.ly/2014/12/spring-15-release-notes-digest.html).
The full release notes [here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/salesforce_release_notes.htm).
There are several blogs out and the topic can be found on the success community [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/topics/TopicPage?id=0TO30000000Dnb2).
[Here](http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/spring15_ReleasePreview.pdf) is a preview of the Spring 15 release.
There is also a "Success - Release Readiness" collaboration group [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oku).

Comment: Jenny Almost covered everything in this answer. Here is one more short blog post written - http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-spring-15-some-highlighted-features/

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of sharing my note on Spring 15 features,

[nazeer-ahamed.blogspot.in](http://nazeer-ahamed.blogspot.in/2015/02/my-take-on-salesforcecom-spring-15.html)